# Run function in background that returns list

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to get my function that makes web-requests for all elements of a list:

```
import myClass

def getForAll(elements):
    myList = []
    for element in elements:
        myList.append([element] + myClass.doThing(element))
    return myList
```

I have tried the following, but it always times out:

```
    import myClass
    from multiprocessing import Pool

def getForAll(elements):
    pool = Pool()
    queries = []
    for element in elements:
        queries.append(pool.apply_async(myClass.doThing, element))
    myList = []
    for query in queries:
        myList.append(query.get(timeout=10))
    return myList
```

It is not a time-issue however, because removing the timeout just causes it to run for ever and ever.

```
queries.append(pool.apply_async(myClass.doThing, [element]))
```

Also didn't make anything different.

For clarification: I call `getForAll()` with a List of Strings, and the function `doThing()` returns a List of Lists of strings. I don't need the order to stay the same, but it would be nice if possible. Also, I don't need to seperate the "CPU-Work" onto several cores, I just don't want to wait about one second per element because `doThing` calls `requests.get()` twice and I believe that can be done for all elements at the same time, without waiting for the response, making the code run at the same speed regardless of the number of elements?

Answer (score 1):

```
import myClass
from multiprocessing import Pool

def getForAll(elements):
    pool = Pool()    
    return pool.map(myClass.doThing, elements)
```

This works perfectly for my usecase. I also had to split my elements up into smaller groups because of the limitations of the API that I was using, with this code from SO:

```
f = lambda A, n=5: [A[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(A), n)]
queries = f(elements)
```